# how do set an attribute of an object to a reference of variable outside of the object

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to make a neural network from scratch.
When creating inputnodes i want to pass in a reference to a variable so i dont have to reset it every time the variable (which the inputnode gets its data from) changes.
this is a simplified version of what i have now:

```
Class values:
    VList1 = [0, 5, 10, 15]

class source:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value

source0 = source(values.VList[1])
print (source0.value)
values.VList[1] = 25
print (source0.value)
```

This will print out:

```
5
5
```

However i want it to print out:

```
5
25
```

Without manually updating source0.value, is there any way i could do this?
Or is there a way to store a reference to `values.VList[1]` in source0?

Comment: Python doesn't have references to variables. It only has references to objects.

Comment: When you do `source(values[1])` it just passes the value that was in `values[1]`, not a reference to that list element. There are no references to elements like that.

Comment: Is there any way it could be done in another way?

Comment: Pass in the list and the index.

Comment: @Barmar `source(values[1])` still passes reference to object `values[1]` [Check this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GcjGKrvca) though I might be wrong.

Comment: It passes a reference to the object that is in the list that is completely independent of the list itself; when the list is changed, the object itself doesn't change, the list does.  Hence you can't get the new list contents without a reference to the *list*.

Comment: @Ch3steR Unfortunately, English doesn't really have good language to describe these distinctions easily. It's much easier to describe if you can talk about the implementation in terms of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `values.VList[1]` in an expression, it is evaluated and returns a reference to the specific `int` that is currently contained in that list; it does not give you a reference to that *location* in the list.

If you want a reference to that list location, store the reference to the list `values` and the index `1` in `source` so that you can use those pieces of information to look up the value that is currently present at that index in the list.  If you want to be able to access `source.value` for convenience, use a `@property`:

```
class values:
    VList = [0, 5, 10, 15]

class source:
    def __init__(self, values, index) -> None:
        self.values = values
        self.index = index
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.values[self.index]


source0 = source(values.VList, 1)
print(source0.value)  # 5
values.VList[1] = 25
print(source0.value)  # 25
```

A better way of structuring this code might be to make this a list of mutable objects (e.g. a `@dataclass` which is the simplest way of making a class whose main purpose is to contain other data), so that you can pass around references to the individual objects:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Source:
    value: int

values = [Source(v) for v in (0, 5, 10, 15)]

source0 = values[1]
print(source0.value)  # 5
values[1].value = 25
print(source0.value)  # 25
```

In the above code, `values` is a list of `Source` objects, each of which stores a reference to a `value` attribute.  `source0` refers to a particular `Source` that is also stored in `values`; when you change that object's `value` through either reference, the change is "visible" via the other reference, because both variables refer to the same `Source` object rather than to different `int` values.

If you did:

```
value0 = values[1].value
```

then `value0` would be a specific `int` that would not update when the original `Source` did.

Comment: I was trying to visualize a descriptor but your dataclass solution is pretty *clean*.